# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor.<init>(

Tags: spring

I am newbie to springs 3.0.And i started with small app that will show firstname,lastname and other properties to jsp in springs. Still i could able to show the message coming from controller but when i trying to get the properties mentioned above, i am facing the Exception regarding the load() exception of my 'spring-servlet.xml' . Still i got the suggestion to check whether ResourceEditor() is present in springs-core jar file.But it is present.I have given my exception trace for your reference. Please suggest me the another option to resolve the issue.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:123)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Aug 09, 2013 10:00:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMVC_Multi_Row threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:123)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your Servlet has a Spring 3 dependency (where the `ResourceEditor(ResourceLoader,PropertyResolver)` constructor is present) but you use a Spring 2 library where no such constructor is available!

Answer (score 4):

Any time I get those kinds of Method Not Found exceptions inside frameworks (especially mature ones) the first thing I do is to look for conflicting dependencies. Sometimes two different libraries include different versions of the same dependency which, in my experience, commonly causes this type of issue.

Comment: Yea, I checked the pom.xml 

"<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>"

and 

"<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>"

Had conflicting versions.